# configuration for flume to write large file in HDFS

Tags: flume

My config file :

```
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks = sink1


agent1.sources.source1.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.source1.spoolDir = /var/SpoolDir


agent1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path =     hdfs://templatecentosbase.oneglobe.com:8020/user/Banking4
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = Banking_Details
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .avro
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.serializer = avro_event
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.serializer = DataStream
#agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.callTimeout = 20000
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollsize = 100000000
#agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.txnEventMax = 40000
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
#agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.codeC = 


agent1.channels.channel1.type = memory
agent1.channels.channel1.capacity = 100000000
agent1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 100000000


agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

Can anyone help me in getting this resolved. Source file is nearly 400MB its writing bits and pieces in HDFS. example ( 1.5mb to 2mb )

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This conf file is writing files in 1mb. I would expect to write files around 100mb!

Comment: atleast changing the conf file will resolve my issue!

Comment: can any one check the configuration file and let me know whether is it capable of writing file of size 100mb in hdfs?